# Session Storage not getting carried forward to new tab in Chrome 89+

Tags: google-chrome, session-storage

I just stumbled upon a problem where Chrome suddenly stopped propagating session storage information when application opened a new tab
This was working fine before then stopped after Chrome 89 update.

Has anyone encountered this issue yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Found the solution in the meantime.

Chrome started changing the behaviour of tabs with target "_blank" recently.

> the HTML standard changed to specify that anchors that target _blank should behave as if |rel="noopener"| is set.
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6140064063029248

The solution is to add rel="opener" if you want the session to be carried over to the new tab.

Comment: We tried this but didn't work for us. Is it still applicable in 2024?

Answer (score 3):

#### reason

> Stop cloning sessionStorage for windows opened with noopener
> https://developer.chrome.com/blog/deps-rems-89/#stop-cloning-sessionstorage-for-windows-opened-with-noopener

#### solution

Add attribute `rel="opener"`.

```
<a href="http://xxx" target="_blank" rel="opener">Link</a>
```

Comment: We tried this but didn't work for us. Is it still applicable in 2024?