# Build communications between tabs

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to create a communication channel between tabs. In my main tab I have the following:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
   console.log(event.data);
}, false);
```

I am opening new tab using this code:

```
window.open('https://localhost/newtab.html', '_blank');
```

In the newtab.html I hav this code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
        window.postMessage('message', 'abc');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Both target tab and new tab are on the same domain.
I am not getting into target tab when opening a new tab. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Comment: I tried localStorage, postMesasge, BroadcastChannel. All the same. I am not getting into the Listener on the main tab. Seems to me it doesn't like that script code I am using in the new tab, or something else.

Comment: This may help someone -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473527/session-storage-not-getting-carried-forward-to-new-tab-in-chrome-89